# Merge and update node values of two xmls using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, osb

I am new bee in XSLT.
But I belive below requirement can be achieved using XSLT :)
Now I have a requirement where i need to merge 2 different xmls to one and there should be a check where the xslt should be capable of checking node name like if input1/nodeName matches to input2/nodeName then value need to be populated from input2.

For Example:

Input1 xml:

```
<Parent>
    <C1>123</C1>
    <C2>Incorrect data</C2>
    <C3>789</C3>
</Parent>
```

Input2 xml:

```
<NewParent>
  <C2>CorrectData</C2>
</NewParent>
```

Output: should be

```
<Parent>
    <C1>123</C1>
    <C2>CorrectData</C2>
    <C3>789</C3>
</Parent>
```

I tried below XSLT to merge both, but found no solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="input1" select="input1.xml" />
    <xsl:param name="input2" select="input2.xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="$input1//node() = $input2//node()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$input2/node()" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the stylesheet terminates with some node-set error.

Note : To get the result we shouln't specify any nodeName(like c1,c2) no where in the XSLT code. It should be generic.

Please let me know if any further information required. And also let me know if my question isn't clear.

Comment: For your next questions, please have a look at the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code.

Comment: Try Oliver Becker's merge algorithm before implementing your own: https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="input1" select="document('input1.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="input2" select="document('input2.xml')" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="$input1/*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name() = $input2//name()">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$input2/*/node()" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Parent>
 <C1>123</C1>
 <C2>CorrectData</C2>
 <C3>789</C3>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Rudramuni - thanks for the reply . i tried the update you suggested but it's not updating the payload, If i apply the above xslt. output iam getting is same input1 xml( as output).

Comment: Uday, check the file names given in XSLT with respect external file names.

Comment: Hi Rudramuni, before i say "i tried what you said..." is it possible for us to execute the xslt code with out giving the phisical location of input xml's inside the xslt code? actualy i have to pass input xml's dynamically(not fetching from pariticular physical location). so xslt to should be capable to receiving the both input(xmls) in param1 and param2 respectivily(is it should be something like this?) please let me know if you need more info... i tried lot many ways but found no luck. help me out in this...

Comment: @UdayShankar, I also tried with dummy input XML, and XSLT is fetching the info from other two XMLs which are located in XSLT script path. Please post a new question with this requirement, so many experts are there in our Stackoverflow site, sure they will suggest you the right one. Did this XSLT worked for you?.

Comment: Rudramuni, yes this worked for me. but with some code modifications, actually i wanna implement this code in OSB. so i had to pass input xmls dynamically (not passing the input with phisical location of xml file). so i have to introduce java - which will convert one of my xml into DOM object. so this xslt needs some code modification. basically to say i took some part of the XSLT code from 1st for-each. thanks a ton. :)